# Avoid fetching credentials multiple times with NextAuth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm currently developing an app using NextAuth v5, and I've structured it similarly to Vercel's chatbot template. One issue I've encountered is the repeated fetching of authentication credentials throughout the app. Despite my limited experience with Next.js, I've been unable to find a method to fetch auth credentials once on the server side and then share the state between server and client components across the entire app.

While many resources suggest using the context API, it doesn't seem to function well in server components. I'm concerned that constantly refetching session credentials is not a good practice, and I find drilling props down the component tree equally undesirable.

Is there a recommended approach for addressing this issue? For reference, authentication credentials are currently being fetched in both the sidebar and the main chat page:

https://github.com/vercel/ai-chatbot/blob/c368a0967cc210cb11c54f1d0ed4511456c0fa3a/components/sidebar-desktop.tsx#L7
https://github.com/vercel/ai-chatbot/blob/c368a0967cc210cb11c54f1d0ed4511456c0fa3a/app/(chat)/chat/%5Bid%5D/page.tsx#L17